# Javascript age is in negative number. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript below, but the age is diplaying in negative numbers. For Example (-338083197987) and it is unrealistics as well. How can age be display in a positive number and more appropriately.

see Javascript below

```
var allPeople = [];
function regBirth() {
    'use strict';
    var myArray = {};
    myArray.fname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    myArray.lname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
    var actualDob = myArray.actualBirthDate;
    actualDob = document.getElementById('birthDate').value

    var currentDate = new Date();
    var birth_date = +new Date(actualDob);
    //var myAge =Math.round((currentDate - birth_date) /31557600000);
    var today_year = currentDate.getFullYear();
    var today_month = currentDate.getMonth();
    var today_day = currentDate.getDate();
    var age = today_year - birth_date;

    if ( today_month < (birth_date - 1))
    {
        age--;
    }

    if (((birth_date - 1) == today_month) && (today_day < birth_date))
    {
        age--;
    }
    console.log(age);

    allPeople.push(myArray);

    var inputForm = document.getElementById("inputFrom").reset();
    var tabularForm = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var tablerow = document.createElement('tr'); 

    var fname = document.createElement('td');
    fname.innerHTML = myArray.fname;
    tablerow.appendChild(fname);

    var lname = document.createElement('td');
    lname.innerHTML = myArray.lname;
    tablerow.appendChild(lname);

    var dob = document.createElement('td');
    dob.innerHTML = actualDob;
    tablerow.appendChild(dob);

    var myBirthDay = document.createElement('td');
    myBirthDay.innerHTML = age;
    tablerow.appendChild(myBirthDay);

    tabularForm.appendChild(tablerow); 
    document.getElementById("details").appendChild(tabularForm);

    console.log(myArray);
    console.log(allPeople.length);

    var totalPeople = allPeople.length;  
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML=totalPeople;
}
```

Comment: "the age is diplaying in negative numbers and it is unrealistics as well".. That's a roundabout way of saying that the age is *completely wrong*.

Comment: You are comparing apples to frogs in your age calculation.  If you have Chrome browser, use Developer tools and run your code under debugger.

Comment: Please help in the coding

Comment: How is the date formated in the element `birthDate` ? You will need to parse this correcty into a javascript date.

Comment: get rid of the plus sign in `var birth_date = +new Date(actualDob);`

Comment: yep..done that already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
var allPeople = [];
function regBirth() {
    'use strict';
```

There does not appear to be any value to using strict here, so probably not worth doing.

```
    var myArray = {};
```

It is misleading to assign a plain Object to a variable called *myArray*, why not *myObject*? Even better to give it a descriptive name reflecting its purpose, e.g. *data* or similar.

```
    myArray.fname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    myArray.lname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
    var actualDob = myArray.actualBirthDate;
```

There is no property *myArray.actualBirthDate*, so *actualDob* will have the value *undefined*.

```
    actualDob = document.getElementById('birthDate').value
```

That replaces the prevoius assignment, making it redundant (i.e. completely unncessary)

```
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var birth_date = +new Date(actualDob);
```

What is the value of *actualDob*? I can assume it's a string, so you are relying on the Date constructor to correctly parse a string, something it is notoriously bad at doing. Anyhow, if it manages to parse it to create a suitable date, the `+` operator in front of *new* will cause *birth_date* to be set to a UTC [time value](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1) representing 00 hrs on that particular date in the locale of the host system (based on system settings).

The time value will be the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, so +ve for dates after then and -ve for dates before. e.g. for say 1985-07-21 it will be 490716000000.

```
    //var myAge =Math.round((currentDate - birth_date) /31557600000);

    var today_year = currentDate.getFullYear();
    var today_month = currentDate.getMonth();
    var today_day = currentDate.getDate();
    var age = today_year - birth_date;
```

Given that *today_year* is a year and *birth_date* is a time value, *age* will be a very large number, either +ve or -ve depending on the date used to create the time value.

If you want to get the difference between two dates in terms hours, minutes an seconds, simply subract one date from another to produce a difference in milliseconds, then convert it to an appropriate format.

If you want to get the difference in years, months and days, a different algorithm is required since years and months are not of even lengths.

I haven't looked at the rest of the code.